# Windows 7 Embedded Standard Offer Remote Assistance Issue

Tags: windows, windows-7, remote-desktop, embedded

I have run into an interesting issue with Remote Assistance on Windows 7 Embedded Standard. I am able to create a Remote Assistance Invitation and use this to connect from a technician PC, but when I attempt to run msra /offerra and specify the computer name I am greeted with the prompt, "Your offer to help could not be sent". I had to manually install the cab using dism. I will quickly outline the steps I took so far.

- Renamed 'remotepg.dl_' to 'remotepg.dll'
- Executed dism /online /add-package /packagepath:
- Restarted the workstation
- Copied msra.exe.mui to %windir%\System32\en-US
- Restarted the workstation again
- Attempted to launch Local Computer Policy and modify the Remote Assistance object and was unable to.
- I copied the admx and adml files from a working Remote Assistance pc and pasted them into %windir%\PolicyDefinitions and en-US on the WS7E unit. This got the Local Computer Policy to load.
- I modified the offer remote assistance settings to what currently are in use on our network.
- Attempted to connect and offerra will only say unable to connect

Here is the package information in case that will help.

```
dism /online /get-packages | findstr RemoteAssistance
Package Identity : WinEmb-RemoteAssistance~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.1.7600.16385
```

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I'm missing something, but why are you setting up / initiating remote assistance requests from Embedded OS's? my experience with any of the Embedded / Starter version OS's everything seems like it should work normally but doesn't, typically reserve these for very light kiosk usage, and setup a third party tool like RealVNC.

but it's possible there is a limiting factor here that I'm not aware of, so again apologize if there's something I'm not taking into account.

Comment: We are actually using WindowsRA to offer support, not initiate the support session from the Windows Embedded device. You can see this functionality by running "msra /offerra" from a Windows prompt. The functionality is present, here is a comparison of the SKUs http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/develop/windows-embedded-standard-7-os-components.aspx. The main issue is that Remote Assistance works, just not when you attempt to offer Remote Assistance.
Thank you for responding.